# How to choose an enum value with a function inside the enum in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, sprite-kit

I'm working to create a SpriteKit game and I'm trying to choose an enum value with a function inside my enum so that I can use each value outside of it.

This is my code:

```
enum Classification: Int, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Circle = 0, Square, Triangle

    var classificationName: String {
        switch self {
        case .Circle:
            return "circle"
        case .Square:
            return "square"
        case .Triangle:
            return "triangle"
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        return self.classificationName
    }

    var classificationSpriteName: String {
        let classificationSpriteName = [
        "circle",
        "square",
        "triangle"
        ]
        return classificationSpriteName[rawValue]
    }

    static func useGeometry() -> Classification {
        return Classification(rawValue: Int())!
    }
}

class Shape: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.column ^ self.row
    }
    var column: Int
    var row: Int
    let shapeType: Classification

    var shapeSprite: SKSpriteNode?

    var classificationName: String {
        return shapeType.classificationName
    }

    ….(code)…

    final class func chosenShape(shapeStartingColumn:Int, shapeStartingRow:Int) -> Shape {
        switch Classification.useGeometry() {
        case .Circle:
            return CircleShape(column:shapeStartingColumn, row:shapeStartingRow, shapeType: Classification(rawValue: 0)!)
        case .Square:
            return SquareShape(column:shapeStartingColumn, row:shapeStartingRow, shapeType: Classification(rawValue: 1)!)
        case .Triangle:
            return SquareShape(column:shapeStartingColumn, row:shapeStartingRow, shapeType: Classification(rawValue: 2)!)

        }
    }
```

I can’t choose anything but the circle.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: what's your issue, exactly?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but please note that while `enum` names start with uppercase letters, `case` names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: Thank you, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this function:

```
static func useGeometry() -> Classification {
    return Classification(rawValue: Int())!
}
```

You are creating a new Classification with a rawValue evaluated by Int(), which is going to return a new Int object with a default value (Int() == 0).

So when you call useGeometry from your switch statement, it's effectively always going to return .Circle, because the rawValue is effectively always 0.

You probably want to pass in an integer, eg maybe the row value?, to useGeometry, something which matches up to a Classification enum value. Something like this:

```
static func useGeometry(value: Int) -> Classification {
    return Classification(rawValue: value)!
}
```

Note: Be careful that you don't call it with an invalid value or you will crash, because you're force unwrapping the result of the constructor. 
And then call it with a value:

```
switch Classification.useGeometry(value: shapeStartingRow) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same problem, because "shapeStartingRow" is the same for each element of Classification (-1). I tried (rawValue: shapeStartingRow + 1) to get .circle,  (rawValue: shapeStartingRow + 2) to get .square, etc, but it always returns .circle. What can I do? Thank you again...

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to be more specific. You haven't included code where you call chosenShape(). Also why not just pass a Classification to chosenShape and use that in the switch? Then you don't need useGeometry at all.

Comment: SOLVED IT! Thanks, thanks a lot. I removed useGeometry and create a separated func for each shape... 
final class func circleShape(shapeStartingColumn:Int, shapeStartingRow:Int) -> Shape {
return CircleShape(column:shapeStartingColumn, row:shapeStartingRow, shapeType: Classification(rawValue: 0)!)

Answer (score 0):

The function `useGeometry` returns `.Circle` every time because you start it with rawValue 0, which is the result of `Int()`.

Implement that funcion to return `self` (shoud not be static anymore) and use `shapeType` in the switch.